# Add debugging to bochs with macports

Tags: macos, debugging, macports, bochs

I can't seem to get debugging working on bochs.  I installed it using macports.  Specifically, when I launch bochs, the command line never appears.

I'm pretty sure I included the debugging variant when I installed it; but, I suppose I could have mis-typed it.

When I run `port installed bochs`, I get this

```
$ port installed bochs
The following ports are currently installed:
  bochs @2.6.8_1+avx+sdl2+smp+term (active)
```

Which seems to suggest the debugging variant isn't installed; but, when I try to add the debugging variant, the response suggests that nothing need be done:

```
$ sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants bochs +debugging
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

Is there another way to verify the presence or absence of debugging, and add it, if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the variant for bochs `debugging` is:

```
+debugger
```

In a standard bochs ./configure the option would be:

```
--enable-debugger
```

↳ https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/emulators/bochs/Portfile#L51

Comment: Close: It was actually `+debugger`.  I also did a `port clean bochs` first.  I'm not sure if that was necessary.

Comment: @Zack: Edited with correct variant option — and good idea on the `port clean bochs`, cheers! :)